# Call validator method in ViewController from the View

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm learning Ext JS 5.1.
Is it possible to call validator method that defined in ViewController from the View?

MyView

```
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        name: 'pass1',
        reference: 'pass1',
        inputType: 'password',
        allowBlank: false,
        minLength: 5
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        fieldLabel: 'Confirm Password',
        name: 'pass2',
        reference: 'pass2',
        inputType: 'password',
        allowBlank: false,
        validator: 'checkPassword' // want to call method that defined in ViewController
    }
```

MyViewController

```
    checkPassword: function(value){
        var pass1val = this.lookupReference('pass1').getValue();
        if (value == pass1val){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return "The initial password and the re-typed password do not match.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current work around for v5.1 is the following (example [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mpn)):

```
      // ...in ViewController
        init: function() {
            var startCombo = this.lookupReference('startCombo');
            var endCombo = this.lookupReference('endCombo');
            startCombo.validator = Ext.bind(this.comboValidator, this, [startCombo, endCombo]);
            endCombo.validator = Ext.bind(this.comboValidator, this, [startCombo, endCombo]);
        },
        comboValidator: function(startCombo, endCombo) {
            return startCombo.getValue() < endCombo.getValue();
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't. But you should be able to. I will log a ticket to get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I'm expectantly waiting for resolve this.